# How to use glibc2.34 on centos7.6?

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, glibc

I was trying to install an software which requires glibc2.34, when I tried to install it, it showed `version 'GLIBC_2.34' not found`.

I tried to install glibc2.34, but after I had installed glibc2.34, I still could not install that software. So I tried to use `strings /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep GLIBC;` and found that glibc2.34 was not supported by the operating system. Who can teach me to solve this problem. I'm a linux noob, so please do let me know if I've said or done anything wrong.

Comment: Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the directory containing the alternate versions of libraries when you run your program. Don't touch the system-installed versions.

Comment: This seems like a great use case for a container runtime like Docker.

Comment: @stark Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to pick a different GLIBC _does not work_ in general. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617

Comment: @EmployedRussian Good to know. I only mentioned it because I use it every day to run a binary from 2002 that I don't have source for.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a linux noob

In that case, your choices are:

- find a build of the software you want to run that was built for your OS (and thus doesn't require GLIBC-2.34), or
- run that software on a system it was built for (i.e. update your OS), or
- run that software in a docker container with GLIBC-2.34 (or newer)

Installing a different GLIBC on the same machine is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617), but complicated.